# Rebex FTPS component takes too long with uploading files

Tags: c#, ftps, rebex

I am trying to upload 230+ files on to an FTPS server using [Rebex's FTP component](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/). All the files TOTAL are like 5MB. so each is a few KB. I upload the file with this line of code:

```
ftps.PutFiles(
    @"C:blablabla*.csv", 
    @"blablafolder/test", 
    FtpBatchTransferOptions.XCopy, 
    FtpActionOnExistingFiles.OverwriteAll);
```

But it takes 2 a 3 hours. Can anyone help explain why this is slow or suggest how this could be done quicker?

EDIT:

Fixed it by doing a for loop and inserting each file with PutFile without S and it works, only now at 180 files it stops, trying to figure this out now, answers are welcome

Answer (score 2):

In general, it can be caused by numerous causes. In the most cases the easiest way how to find out what is going on is to create a communication log and investigate it in detail. It can be done as described [here](http://forum.rebex.net/questions/10/how-to-create-a-log-of-communication-between-component-and-server). If you send me the log file I can help you with it.

You are also welcome to ask questions about Rebex products on our [forum](http://forum.rebex.net). Actually, it is checked every business day by the component developers themselves.

Btw. `FtpBatchTransferOptions.XCopy` option traverses whole directory structure (including all subdirectories). If this is not needed feature you can try this line to speed up whole process:

```
ftps.PutFiles(
    @"C:\blablabla\*.csv", 
    @"blablafolder/test", 
    FtpBatchTransferOptions.Default, 
    FtpActionOnExistingFiles.OverwriteAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you tried uploading it with a regular ftp client?
2. Are you 100% certain that bandwidth is not the limiting factor (both client and server side)?
3. (ie have you proven that you can achieve higher speeds)?

Try http://winscp.net/eng/index.php